# How cast to subclass of object class without use instanceof in JAVA?

Tags: java, javafx, casting, instance, declaration

I'm having trouble making cast from extended Object class to its subclass.
Following this code template.

```
public class Athletic1 extends Object {
      public void run(){
              // run 5km
      }         
}

public class Athletic2 extends Object {

      public void run(){
            // run 10km
      }
}

class SpecificClass{
      // receive an athletic
      SpecificClass(Object obj){
            // HERE i like do something as
            // The left side dont Work
            (obj.getClass().getName) nameVariable = (obj.getClass().getName()) obj;
       }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
          Athletic1 a1 = new Athletic1();
          Athletic2 a2 = new Athletic2();
          SpecificClass sc1 = new SpecificClass(a1);
          SpecificClass sc2 = new SpecificClass(a2);
    }
}
```

I could resort to instanceOf, however when I have lots of subclass amounts of Object, the code becomes very extensive. Is there an alternative?

```
        // Supose that i hava 10 Athletic Class
        // I have that do this????????
        if (obj instanceOf Athletic1)
             Athletic1 a1 = (Athletic1) obj;
        ...
        ...
        else{
             Athletic1 a10 = (Athletic10) obj;
        }
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should look at using [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Comment: What you may wish to do is have both classes implement a common interface.  Say `interface Runner` with common method `run()`.

Comment: What are you planing to do after this cast? Since the common supertype of both classes is `Object`, there's nothing you could do couldn't do with `Object` unless you do some case distinction on the type of the object.

Comment: @fabian yes, i mean. it was a lot of time and i adpted my request from my code, i dont remember now but was a little diffetent. 
A dont have know and not pratice about the right design parttern and i need review some documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typecasts cannot be used in a dynamic fashion as you are attempting.  Here are some of the problems in what you are trying to do:

```
(obj.getClass().getName()) obj;
```

The "stuff" inside the brackets must be an *identifier* not an *expression*.  That identifier needs to be the name of an actual class or an actual interface that is known at compile time.  It cannot be the identifier for a variable.  It cannot even be the identifier for a type parameter.

```
(obj.getClass().getName) nameVariable = ...
```

This is simply wrong.  There is no syntax that would allow you to use a typecast on the left hand side of an assignment like that.

---

So is it possible to "subclass" an instance avoid using `instanceof`?

The `instanceof` is NOT being used to do the subclassing.  The type cast is doing that!  The `instanceof` is actually being used to discriminate the subclasses.

It is possible (though probably not what you want!) to discriminate without using `instanceof`.

1. Use `switch` on the class name:

   ```
   switch (obj.getClass().getName()) {
   case "a.b.Athletic1":
       Athletic1 a1 = (Athletic1) obj;
       // do stuff
       break;
       ...
   case "a.b.Athletic10":
       Athletic10 a10 = (Athletic10) obj;
       // do stuff
   }
   ```

   Problem: you still have boilerplate code to discriminate a fixed number of cases.
2. Use a `Map`.

   ```
   Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> mapping = new Map<> {{
       put(a.b.Athletic1.class, 
           o -> {
               Athletic1 a1 = (Athletic1) o;
               // do stuff
           });
       put(a.b.Athletic10.class, 
           o -> {
               Athletic10 a10 = (Athletic10) o;
               // do stuff
           });
   }};

   Consumer<Object> c = mapping.get(obj.getClass());
   if (c != null) {
       c.accept(obj);
   }
   ```

   Advantages:

   - The map can be populated dynamically.
   - If you need to the `Consumer` objects could be created dynamically as proxy classes.  (Though that is expensive!)

   Disadvantage: still a lot of boilerplate.

While these avoid an explicit `instanceof`, (IMO) these are just as bad as your existing approach.  The "code smell" still exists.

---

IMO, the real solution is to use Java polymorphism.

1. Create a commons superclass / interface for the `Athletic` classes.
2. Create a method in the superclass / interface that represents the action
3. Implement the action method in each of the `Athletic` classes.
4. Call it ...

Comment: You're right, I understand. I will wait for more answers, however, I think your answer will be correct. Thank you community.

Comment: "It cannot even be the identifier for a type parameter." `(E) obj` works just fine.

Comment: Only if the typecast is really a typecast to the baseclass of `E`.  The problem is that the actual class of `E` is not known / passed to the generic method at runtime.  (Type erasure).  So yes, it may "work", but probably not in a way that helps the OP.